# Can one sell the game made in unity free version?

Tags: unity

I'm just getting into it and soon my first project will be done. Can I sell it afterwards?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you'll easily find the answer in the [Unity FAQ](http://unity3d.com/unity/faq).

Comment: It's already  answered. Close it if you want or just leave for other people

Comment: @Brsgamer I asked you once before already. Please search the site before asking questions. Your question was asked already, and it was even asked fairly recently. Continued low quality questions will result in a temporary suspension of ask privileges.

Comment: Yeah.... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

http://unity3d.com/unity/faq

> Yes you can create and sell a game with the free version of Unity, without paying royalties or any revenue share. However, Unity Free, which includes the free platform add-on products, may not be licensed or used by a commercial entity with annual gross revenues (based on prior fiscal year) in excess of US$100,000, or by an educational, academic, non-profit or government entity with a total annual budget for the entire entity (based on prior fiscal year) in excess of US$100,000.